# Change input field value in form before sending

Tags: html, jquery

I have input field to payment gate that creates URL, need to add "00" at the end of entered value.
So right now when I type 150, value to url should go 15000, but user in input file should see still 150

```
<input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 40px;" name="z24_kwota">
```

Full code:

```
<form action="https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php" method="get"><input name="z24_id_sprzedawcy" type="hidden" value="xxx" /> <input name="z24_crc" type="hidden" value="xxx" /> <input name="z24_nazwa" type="hidden" value="xxx" /> <input name="z24_return_url" type="hidden" value="xxx" /> <input name="z24_language" type="hidden" value="pl" />
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 40px;" name="z24_kwota"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p><input id="submit_button" class="button" type="submit" value="PAY" /><br /><br /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You've flagged this with `jQuery`, but haven't show any code. What does your submit code look like?

Comment: I'm still not seeing any jQuery here. What have you attempted to achieve your desired result?

Comment: Yeah better if you add your jQuery code so we know how to help you more. But anyways I show in my answer how to change the value like you want using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by handling the onsubmit event on the form (add `onsubmit="something()"`):

`<form action="https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php" method="get" onsubmit="mySubmit()">`

Then do what you need in the handler:

```
function mySubmit() {
    var el = $("[name=z24_kwota]");
    var val = el.val();
    val *= 100;
    el.val(val);
}
```

When the user clicks the submit button, the `onsubmit` event on the form is triggered which calls the `mySubmit` function. This function alters the value of the element in question (makes 150 => 15000) by multiplying by 100.